Confusion with async task running in unexpected order
I call a method from here:
public async void LoadingWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<(string fileName, string folderName, string destFolder)> filesToDownload = new()
    {
        ("MainDatabase.db", "database", Database),
        ("file1.py", "Resources", Scripts),
        ("file2.py", "Resources", Scripts),
        ("file3.py", "Resources", Utils),
    };

    foreach (var (fileName, folderName, destFolder) in filesToDownload)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => blobMan.DownloadFileStdAsync(fileName, 
            folderName, destFolder, this));
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}

which calls this function:
public async Task DownloadFileStdAsync(string fileName, string folderName,
    string destPath, IProgressReporter progressReporter)
{
    string finalDest = Path.Combine(destPath, fileName);
    string blobName = fileName;

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        "myaccount;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient
        .GetBlobContainerClient("myblob");

    try
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient
            .GetBlobClient(Path.Combine(folderName, blobName));
        progressReporter.ReportProgress(
            $"Downloading Blob '{blobName}' to '{finalDest}'.");

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(finalDest))
        {
            await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fs);
        }

        progressReporter.ReportProgress(
            $"Blob '{blobName}' downloaded successfully to '{finalDest}'.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        progressReporter.ReportProgress($"Error downloading blob: {ex.Message}");
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"error downloading {blobName}, {ex.Message}");
    }
}

For some reason when the execution reaches this point in the method DownloadFileStdAsync:
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fs);

it jumps back at the beginning of the method and starts again with the same fileName parameter:
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fs);  // (is executed again)

So it pops an exception because the file being created is already open in another thread.
Why is this behavior? I expect that the method continues after the await call is finished.

Save (fileName, folderName, destFolder) into separate variable and see mirracle happen =)

Unrelated, but you should not be creating the BlobServiceClient repeatedly. Instead create it and reuse.

Task.Run serves no purpose. It fires off a task that's never awaited and may never complete. This causes the problem too, due to variable capture. blobClient.DownloadToAsync is already asynchronous.

In short, create the service and container client outside the loop and call only await blobClient.DownloadToAsync() inside the loop.

I can't see any problem with your code. As far as I can see everything should be running sequentially, without any concurrency.

@eocron OP uses foreach not for and for foreach it should have been fixed at the moment of async introduction.

Just to be sure - 1) is this the actual code 2) are you sure that the containing method is not called multiple times (i.e. method containing .. filesToDownload = ...)?

@Guru Stron

yes why?
the call of the method is shown in the first code block and the method is called only from there (foreach (var (fileName, folderName, destFolder) in filesToDownload)
{
await Task.Run(() => blobMan.DownloadFileStdAsync(fileName, folderName, destFolder, this));
await Task.Delay(500);
})



as I wrote - just to be sure, because I agree with @TheodorZoulias here - the shown code should work as expected 2) you have misunderstood the question -  I was not asking who and how is calling DownloadFileStdAsync I was asking who and how is calling the containing method (the one with List<(string fileName, string folderName, string destFolder)> filesToDownload = new ...)


@Guru Stron the containing method is called by public async void LoadingWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) so when the wpf form is loaded it calls the method.

The LoadingWindow_Loaded is public, which is strange for an event handler. Are you sure that it's not called directly from somewhere else, apart from the Loaded event handler? Also please confirm that you haven't subscribed to the event twice by mistake.

It looks like LoadingWindow_Loaded is called multiple times.
It could because you're debugging, and the focus changes between your app and Visual Studio [when a breakpoint is hit].)
